# solve the singularities of parabolic orbits of schubert cells

Tags: algebraic-groups, resolution-of-singularities, rt.representation-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let G a semsisimple connect'ed group over $k$, $B$ a Borel and $P$ a parabolic subgroup of $G$ with Weyl group W_{P}.

For $w\in W_{P}\backslash W/W_{P}$, how can we solve the singularities of $X_{w}=\overline{PwP}/P\subset G/P$?

By solving, the singularities, I want that the the resulting

$\pi:Y\rightarrow X_{w}$

is an isomorphism on $PwP/P$.

Comment: I remark that the OP has never voted up or down any question or answer.

Comment: $P$-orbit closures are $B$-orbit closures. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott%E2%80%93Samelson_variety

Comment: yes but a resolution of singularities of $\overline{BwP}$ is birational on $BwP$ and not on $PwP$ a priori


Comment: Why that's true! This sounds like a rather hard question.

Comment: Perhaps this paper may help you in some special cases : http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601117